# Backbone history not filling when using tap event

Tags: events, mobile, backbone.js, router, tap

I'm using backbone for a mobile app dev project (phonegap compiled) but have a problem with the router history. I'm firing the events on tap for extra responsiveness on the mobile platform, however pages visited by triggering tap do not appear to be included in the router's history. When hitting the back button, those are always skipped.

Is there any way to make the backbone router's history work with the tap event?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You must call use the navigate method in order to add a page to Backbone history. You can do it programmatically as follows:

```
var MyApp = new Backbone.Router();
MyApp.navigate('newPage', {trigger: true});
```

Basically whenever you fire a tap event you can navigate to a particular based on the tap event parameters.

Comment: hmm unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. The page flashes back for an instant to the correct screen, but then goes all the way back to the initial screen (the default loaded screen)